# Find jordan from of matrix

Tags: jordan-normal-form

I' am trying to find Jordan form of given matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
So far i founD characteristic  polynomial : $(1 - \lambda )[(1-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)+2]$, eingenvalue: $\lambda = 1$ and eigenvector: $(1,0,-1)$. Now i need to find basis for matrix but i don't know how to do this if there is only one eigenvector.

Comment: Have you been instructed to put it in Jordan form as a *real* matrix? Usually, one refers to plain Jordan form when he's working on an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of the characteristic polynomial are $1$, $i$, and $-i$. So, the Jordan normal form of your matrix is the diagonal matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&i&0\\0&0&-i\end{bmatrix}.$$